# Установить свойство IsChecked у первого RadioButton, если список этих контролов загружаются динамически

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

У меня данные грузятся из БД, и в динамически создается список из RadioButton'ов. Вот как выглядит мой ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Woods}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton    Content="{Binding Name}"
                            GroupName="WoodGroup"
                            FontSize="10"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.RequestWoodChange, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Page}}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Вопрос довольно легкий по идее, но я не могу его решить. Как установить, чтобы первый RadioButton был выбран( IsChecked=true )?
Суть в том, что в VM нет свойства IsChecked, оно и не нужно впринципе

Comment: если `IsChecked` вам не нужно, зачем вы его используете?

Comment: Тогда расскажите о смысле вашей VM. Какой смысл вашей команды `RequestWoodChange`?

Comment: @tym32167 дело в том, что когда я запускаю приложение, то не один из группы RadioButton'ов не выбран. А мне нужно сделать, чтобы всегда был хотя бы один выбран.

Comment: @VladD при срабатывании команды `RequestWoodChange`, я получаю в обработчике сразу объект `Wood` в параметре, что очень удобно, нежели получать номер, потом искать его в коллекции и тд

Comment: @Bretbas: Это понятно, а какой смысл вашей команды? Что она делает?

Comment: @VladD У меня есть открытое свойство `public Wood CurrentWood { get { .. } set { .. } }`, обработчик просто присваивает этому свойству новое значение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный в таких случаях способ - создать обертку, я использую примерно такую, универсальную:

```
class Wrapper<T> : Vm
{
    public T Value { get; }
    public Wrapper(T value) => Value = value;

    bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => isChecked;
        set
        {
            if (Set(ref isChecked, value))
                CheckedChanged?.Invoke(Value, IsChecked);
        }
    }

    public event Action<T, bool> CheckedChanged;
}
```

Для удобства здесь определено событие, на которое мы подпишемся.

Итак, пусть у меня есть некий VM-класс:

```
class TravelMethod : Vm
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public TravelMethod(string name) => Name = name;
}
```

и в главной VM коллекция объектов этого класса и свойство для выбранного элемента:

```
class MainVM : Vm
{
    public ObservableCollection<TravelMethod> TravelMethods { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<TravelMethod>
    {
        new TravelMethod("Walk"),
        new TravelMethod("Bicycle"),
        new TravelMethod("Car"),
        new TravelMethod("Train"),
        new TravelMethod("Plane")
    };

    TravelMethod selectedTravelMethod;
    public TravelMethod SelectedTravelMethod
    {
        get => selectedTravelMethod;
        set => Set(ref selectedTravelMethod, value);
    }
```

На основе этой коллекции нам нужно сгенерировать коллекцию оберток, я делаю это в конструкторе, вы же сами определите нужный момент - скорее всего это будет после загрузки данных из БД:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Wrapper<TravelMethod>> WrappedTravelMethods { get; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        WrappedTravelMethods
            = new ObservableCollection<Wrapper<TravelMethod>>(
                TravelMethods.Select(t => new Wrapper<TravelMethod>(t)));
        foreach (var wtm in WrappedTravelMethods)
            wtm.CheckedChanged += WtmCheckedChanged;
    }

    private void WtmCheckedChanged(TravelMethod travelMethod, bool isChecked)
    {
        if (isChecked) SelectedTravelMethod = travelMethod;
    }
}
```

При установке флага IsChecked мы устанавливаем в качестве текущего этот выбранный элемент.

Теперь, чтобы при запуске сразу установить первый элемент в качестве выбранного нужно добавить в конструкторе простую строчку:

```
        WrappedTravelMethods[0].IsChecked = true;
```

Разметка для тестирования:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WrappedTravelMethods}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding Value.Name}"
                             IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                             GroupName="1"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedTravelMethod.Name}"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: Travels]

Comment: Блин, не хотелось, конечно, вводить свойство IsChecked в VM, но если это единственный способ реализовать текущую задачу, то спасибо:)

Comment: @Bretbas, можно попробовать сочинить конвертер, но там будет решение достаточно громоздкое, поэтому оно вам еще меньше понравится

Comment: Ну о конвертере я сам думал, даже начал реализовывать, и понял что там полный трешебл будет:) Не стал

Comment: Ну, кстати, с конвертером кода примерно столько же (см. соседний ответ). Если ещё сделать конвертер расширением разметки, то ещё удастся выкинуть добавление ресурса

Comment: У меня все конвертеры наследуют от BaseConverter, который в свою очередь реализует MarkupExstention. Поэтому все конвертеры в моем проекте являются расширением разметки:)

Answer (score 3):

Ну например. Ваш RadioButton должен быть выбран тогда, когда текущий `WoodVM` равен `CurrentWood`? Ну так и отлично, привяжите это условие к `IsChecked` через конвертер.

Получится такой код:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Woods}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <local:ObjectsEqualConverter x:Key="ObjectsEqualConverter"/>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton
                Content="{Binding Name}"
                GroupName="WoodGroup"
                FontSize="10"
                Command="{Binding DataContext.RequestWoodChange,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" 
                   CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                <RadioButton.IsChecked>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ObjectsEqualConverter}"
                                  Mode="OneWay">
                        <Binding Mode="OneWay"/>
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.CurrentWood"
                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                       AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </RadioButton.IsChecked>
            </RadioButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Конвертер получается очень простой:

```
class ObjectsEqualConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type tt, object p, CultureInfo ci) =>
        values[0] == values[1];
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] tt, object p, CultureInfo ci) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Только не забудьте в вашей VM присвоить начальное значение свойству `CurrentWood`.

У меня при старте получилось так:

[image: а я ещё палисандр знаю, вот!]

---

На всякий случай, мои VM-классы:

```
class MainVM : VM // реализует INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IEnumerable<WoodVM> Woods { get; } =
        new[] { new WoodVM("Дуб"), new WoodVM("Сосна"), new WoodVM("Кедр"),
                new WoodVM("Ель"), new WoodVM("Ольха") }; // начальное значение для теста

    WoodVM currentWood;
    public WoodVM CurrentWood
    {
        get => currentWood;
        set => Set(ref currentWood, value);
    }

    public ICommand RequestWoodChange { get; }
    public MainVM()
    {
        RequestWoodChange = new SimpleCommand<WoodVM>(v => CurrentWood = v);
        CurrentWood = Woods.First();
    }
}

class WoodVM : VM
{
    public WoodVM(string name) => Name = name;
    public string Name { get; }
}
```

Comment: А можете по подробнее рассказать о привязывании вашего конвертера в xaml? Я не понимаю, что значит `<Binding Mode="OneWay"/>` и ` <Binding Path="DataContext.CurrentWood" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>`. Ну нельзя сказать, что я вообще не понимаю, где-то я догадываюсь конечно. Но все таки хотел бы услышать:)

Comment: @Bretbas: Ну, вы знаете, что такое `MultiBinding`? Это такая штука, которая привязывает несколько VM-значений к одному свойству. Эти самые VM-значения задаётся привязками. Ну вот, `<Binding/>` — это как обычно привязка к текущему `DataContext`'у. Окей? А у привязки можно указать, чтобы она была односторонней (`Mode="OneWay"`), только из VM к V. Зачем односторонняя привязка? Ну, чтобы если `IsChecked` изменится, чтобы фреймворк не пытался через `ConvertBack` присвоить значения назад в VM-свойства.

Comment: @Bretbas: А вторая часть ничем не отличается от вашей привязки `Command`. Ну только записано не в форме атрибута, а в форме вложенного тега (но это то же самое).

Comment: спасибо большое:)

Comment: @Bretbas: Пожалуйста!