# WPF Checkboxes in Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, combobox

Как достать Content только тех checkbox'ов (в C#), которые нажаты на данный момент?

```
  <ComboBox Name="LeagueClub" ItemsSource="{Binding Leagues}" Width="370">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
              <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"></CheckBox>
           </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Добавить в Vm свойство `IsChecked`

Comment: А откуда мы знаем, какие свойства есть в вашей VM?

Comment: @VladD, Leagues - список string

Comment: @NickLaptev: На уровне VM у вас нету доступа к View. Поэтому вот так прямо не выйдет. Ну это и понятно: семантика вашей операции должна быть на VM-уровне, а у вас на уровне View. Расскажите лучше, какая цель вашего кода.

Comment: @VladD: У меня есть выпадающий список checkbox'ов с названиями различных чемпионатов. Мне надо каким-то образом достать отмеченные чемпионаты, чтобы в последующем я мог их добавить в базу данных

Comment: @NickLaptev  вам же уже посоветовали в начале создайте свойство IsChecked. Очевидно, что ваш список string нужно просто заменить на класс с двумя свойствами: string и bool. А в CheckBox привяжите свойство IsChecked к своему bool.

Comment: @John: Это не лучшая идея — менять VM под нужды конкретного View. Лучше написать wrapper, как в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/751434/10105

Comment: @VladD То есть как? VM - это прослойка между Model и View, и она создаётся, как раз на основе конкретного View. В твоём примере, кстати этот принцип нарушается: у него список string и список wrapper находится в VM, что в общем-то неправильно. Сам список должен находится в Model, а в VM создаваться лишь список wrapper основанный на модели.

Comment: @John: Не-а. VM вообще не должна знать, показывается ли она во View, а если показывается, то в скольких View. Если создавать VM под конкретный View, то зачем самому себе усложнять жизнь? Тогда можно всё сделать в code-behind.

Comment: @VladD Она и не знает. Мы не передаём ссылку на View во VM. Мы создаёт конкретные поля с конкретными именами основывая на нашем View. И при выставлении DataContext наша View привязывается к свойствам по именам, которые мы задали. Ты не можешь создавать VM не зная, какая у тебя View.

Comment: @John: Знает, раз мы специально под View создаём поле `IsChecked`. Эта VM заточена под использование с `CheckBox`'ом. А VM я создаю всю жизнь без оглядки на View, брат жив, зависимости нет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69558/discussion-between-john-and-vladd).

Answer (score 0):

если, КМК, вы не используете MVVM, то простой путь мог бы выглядеть так:

1) поименовать StackPanel;

2) в коде C# выбрать из перечисления его дочерних элементов (они все только чекбоксы?) с помощью предикатов только (isCheked=true), т.е. например для:

**XAML:**

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Content="Aa" IsChecked="True"></CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Content="Bb" IsChecked="False"></CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Content="Cc" IsChecked="True"></CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

**C#**

```
var chekedContents = comboBox.Items.OfType<ComboBoxItem>().Where(cbi => ((((StackPanel)cbi.Content).Children[0].GetType() == typeof(CheckBox)) &
                                                                        (((CheckBox)((StackPanel)cbi.Content).Children[0]).IsChecked == true)
                                                                        )
                                                                )
                                                            .Select(cbi => new { ((CheckBox)((StackPanel)cbi.Content).Children[0]).Content }.ToString());
```

таким громоздким и немного корявым образом мы получим множество объектов с единственным свойством (string)Content

Comment: а разве `comboBox.Items.OfType<ComboBoxItem>().Where(cbi => cbi.IsChecked).Select(cbi => cbi.Content).ToArray()` работать не будет?

Comment: @Foggy Finder, увы (только что проверил) не сработает -- у ComboBoxItem нет свойства IsChecked, он как базовый элемент-"обёртка" для содержимого комбобокса;
IsChecked есть у чекбокса, но до него надо "докопаться" -- я кстати так и не понял, зачем топикстартер положил единственный элемент (CheckBox) в StackPanel, это же ничего не даст.

Comment: да, это я неподумавши написал :(