# Как сделать множественный выбор данных в combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

У меня есть данные которые я вывожу в ComboBox. Мне нужно сделать множественный выбор данных в комбобоксе. Как реализовать множественный выбор данных в комбобоксе и при нажатии на клавишу вывести список id + fio пользователей в консоль? Подскажите пожалуйста.

**view.xaml:**

```
<ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Workers}">
          <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
              <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                   <CheckBox Content="{Binding FIO}"
                             Tag="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}" />
              </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
          </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**viewModel.cs:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Workers = new ObservableCollection<UserInfo>();
    }

    public ICollection<UserInfo> Workers { get; set; }

    protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        var workers = await _procedures.GetUsers();
        Workers.ReplaceRange(workers);
    }
}
```

**UserInfo.cs:**

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public string FIO { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону CheckedListBox.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, в WPF такого нет

Comment: @АндрейNOP гугл говорит что способы все же есть...

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, ну этим WPF и хорош, что в нем всё это можно сделать, в том числе и **выпадающий** список с чекбоксами. Но зачем предлагать контрол, которого нет в штатной поставке и который не тот что нужен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам придется делать VM-обертку для вашей сущности, включающей свойство вроде `bool IsChecked` (привяжете его к IsChecked CheckBox'а).

Потом все просто, выбираем выделенные: `Workers.Where(w => w.IsChecked)` и делаем с ними все что нужно.

Штатных средств для множественного выбора в ComboBox нет.

Comment: Можно поподробнее что такое vm-обертка и как ее делать? я недавно только начал осваивать mvvm (если это относится к этому) Я пробовал добавить свойство во ViewModel IsChecked, но в view.xaml в checkbox нельзя выбрать это свойство так как там элементы только из UserInfo

Comment: Пример обертки здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/751434/218063