# WPF(MVVM) Как реализовать аналог "Прокачка скиллов"

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Имеется коллекция из 4 умений.На каждом уровне можно изучить только 1 из 4 умений.Также можно изменять выбор на любой из колонны.При этом, при нажатии на выбранном элементе opacity становится 1, а на предыдущем возвращается в исходное для затемнения.Привожу гиф демонстрацию и ViewModel(для примера MVVM).Каким элементом это возможно реализовать? Как организовать хранение выбранных элементов в последствии? Это всё будет сохраняться в json для последующей загрузки.Использую библиотеку MVVM-Light

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по описанию вам нужен обычный `RadioButton`, просто кастомизируйте его.

Comment: Благодарю за совет.Не могли бы вы посоветовать, каким образом хранить выбранные позиции? Коллекция для каждого столбца\строки или есть иной способ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/751434/218063